# Mongoose Find not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, express, mongoose

This is my first time writing a MVC app in Node/Express/Mongoose so I could really use some help. My .find() command just doesn't find anything! :(

Structure is that I have a an /app folder in the root. /app folder contains /models (schemas), /controllers and /views in it. And I have app.js outside in the root.

Somewhere in app.js:

```
// all necessary config/setup stuff..
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(config.db);
var app = express();
require('./config/routes')(app)
```

In my routes.js file:

```
var skills = require('../app/controllers/skills');
app.get('/', skills.showall);
```

My controller skills.js contains:

```
var Skill = require('../models/skill');

exports.showall = function(req, res) {
    Skill.find({}, function(err, docs){
        if (!err) {
            res.render('index', {title: 'Skilldom', skills: docs});
        }
        else {
            throw err;
        }
    });
}
```

Finally my Model skill.js contains:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Skill schema definition
var skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    length: String,
});

var Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillSchema);

module.exports = Skill;
```

My index view renders, so I see the content from my index.jade template, but for some reason the find command in the model is not fetching anything. I can confirm that my database (in MongoHQ) has real data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you use Mongoose to insert the data into your database, or did it get there by some other means?

Comment: In that case, you have to be aware how Mongoose names the collections that models are stored in (for instance, a `Skill` model will probably be stored in a collection called `skills`). See [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) on how to manually set the collection name.

Answer (score 13):

Change your `Skill.js` for this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

//Skill schema definition

var skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  length: String,
});

var Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillSchema);
module.exports = Skill;
```

After that, you can see at the console if mongoose is doing your queries.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation as you describe and it turns out I didn't understand the magic of mongoose collection naming, in your code it will try to load the "skills" and if that's not what it's named in your mongo nothing will be returned. Should really toss a "so such collection" error instead imho.

Answer (score 0):

This below method gives an alternate name for your collection

```
var skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  length: String,
},{collection : 'Skill'});

or 

var Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillSchema,''Skill);
```